# UITableViewController section header and footer no showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Swift 3, XCode 8.3
Dynamic Prototype cells. The view (class `CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController`) is in a separate storyboard which is referenced from another storyboard, with a segue from a table which itself is embedded in a Nav Controller.

The following methods are implemented:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
```

If I embed viewcontroller in navcontroller, `viewForFooterInSection` will get called and view will be visible. `willDisplayHeaderView` is still not called. **EDIT**: it is not embedding it is setting my CustomTableViewController as Initial View Controller. When Nav Controller is IVC then viewForFooterInSection is called, when CustomTableViewController (embedded in Nav Controller) is IVC viewForFooterInSection is not called.

If I change table to static cells, `willDisplayHeaderView` would get called and `viewForFooterInSection` will get called, but once again only if view is embedded into Nav Controller.

Embedding in another Nav Controller has side effects that I am trying to avoid, but in any case `willDisplayHeaderView` is not called.

Comment: This was an internal bug with implementation of unrelated framework. Implementing required methods works. This is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot these delegates:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

The same for header. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Add the delegate methods for

1. Height for Header (Return appropriate height for Header)
2. View for Header
3. Height for Footer (Return appropriate height for Footer)
4. View for Footer

Check Delegate and datasource are assigned to table if you are using table inside Viewcontroller.

Comment: Its a class CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController ... yes delegates are assigned correctly. And at least viewForFooterInSection is called when embedded in Nav Controller...

Answer (score 0):

You can implement following methods of table view

```
extension DemoViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

//setting header height to 100
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

//setting footer height to 100
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

//setting header view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return headerView
}

//setting footer view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    return footerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    //customization for footer goes here
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    //customization for header goes here
}
}
```

Comment: I thought I made it clear that these methods are implemented, but viewForFooterInSection is not called when not embedded in Nav Controller. And willDisplayXXXX is not called when using Dynamic Prototypes for cells.